# How Add Action to Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a question about actions on Struts 2.

Suppose I have a form with the action `"save"`

And I have maped on my struts.xml that action to some method, like this:

```xml
<action name="save" class="actions.agenda" method="save">
            <result name="success">/agenda/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

On my Action class I use the execute to load some parameters in the form, so I have created the method to save the new entry:

```
public String save(){
        ///Logic here
        dao.create(entry)
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The problem is I'm having this error:

**SEVERE: Could not find action or result**

Someone can give me clues about this problem :)?

**web.xml**

```xml
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
    <filter-name>springOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

.....

</web-app>
```

I have my action (save) on an separate xml called "Actions.xml" and is Included on struts.xml

**Stacktrace**

```
Stacktraces
No result defined for action actions.agenda and result input

    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:376)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

other actions works fine.

Comment: is any of our `action`s defined in the struts.xml working? Do you have those `JSP` files on the [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)?

Comment: Do you have more code from the struts.xml? I would guess it couldn't find the JSP or you need to point the form to *save.action* ... well at least if your default web.xml code is this: '    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>' ... if you showed us the form you use, and the filter-mapping of your web.xml it would maybe help too.

Comment: You're getting a validation/type conversion error somewhere.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but could you post the form HTML / JSP? From which URL does the form call the action? Is is from a domain.tld/path/something.jsp? Can you confirm the fully qualified package of the action is actions.agenda without anything before that? Is the action public? Does it inherit from ActionSupport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complaint that you're actually getting is `No result defined for action actions.agenda and result input`.  Basically this means that something caused Struts to believe you're providing invalid data to one of the properties (or the validate method added a field/action error).

e.g. Maybe you have a setter that takes an integer that you're passing a non-integer value to, something like that.  Because it can't do the conversion from the provided value to one appropriate for the setter, it'll complain.

This causes the action to return a value of 'INPUT', for which you have no result defined.  Usually what would be done here is return the same form that was presented before the save for 'input' results, as the normal Struts 2 tags, like `<s:textfield>` or `<s:select>` will display field errors above the corresponding fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit a form you should provide an `input` type result. So

```
<action name="save" class="actions.agenda" method="save">
  <result name="success">/agenda/success.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">/agenda/myjspwithform.jsp</result>       
</action>
```